# Allow file to be read by only system command in a C Program

Tags: files, permissions, privileges

I have a C program `program.c` that contains a `system("/bin/cat file.txt")` command, where `file.txt` is a file in the same directory as the C program. Now I would like to prevent users to read file.txt by simply `cat file.txt`. However, when they run `./program 1234` the system command should show the `file.txt` contents. How can I modify file permissions to do this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the owner and suid bit for the C program executable and making `file.txt` readable by that owner only?

Comment: you cant do that with permissions - there is essentially no difference between your system command and the user's shell. you might compile file.txt into your program - have your preprocessor insert it and do the equivalent of `cat <<file.txt\n....\nfile.txt\n`

Comment: @Anthon - that would require a separate user for the one program.

Comment: How can it be done with a separate user?

Answer (score 2):

To give a process elevated permissions (in this case, being able to read the file while regular users can't) is exactly the functionality of SUID/SGID. Do read up on the whole UID/EUID mess, it isn't exactly trivial.

You *might* get away by creating a group for this, make the file owned by that group, writeable only by e.g. root and readable by the group, with the program SGID. Something like this is  used by games to restrict writing of high-scores files.